# Why is my screen completely white with 'Success' in the top left after logging into Facebook on a tablet?

Tags: android, flash, facebook, actionscript, facebook-actionscript-api

This issue is being tracked on the facebook-actionscript-api site here:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=352&q=label%3APriority-Medium

What steps will reproduce the problem?

> 1. Call FacebookMobile.login(APP_ID, cbLogin) on an Android tablet.
> 2. Enter Facebook account credentials and press "Login".

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

> -Expected: The login window closes and returns to the screen that
>   launched the login window. The callback function 'cbLogin' is called.
>
> -Actual: The screen goes completely white, and has 'Success' in small black text in the >top left corner of the screen. The callback function 'cbLogin' is never called.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?

```
-Android v3.2
-facebook-actionscript-ap v1.7
-ASUS Eee Pad Transformer TF101
```

I've tested this on 2 Android phones, the HTC Incredible (Android v2.2) and the HTC Thunderbolt (Android v2.2.1), and it works fine on both. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the `redirect_uri` parameter may not be set to the desired destination page. Note that at some point in the past the parameter was named `next`, so the library you are using may need to be updated accordingly to support the newer OAuth 2.0 flow. You can find more details about this on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

What is the URL of the page that displays the word "Success"? (Don't include private query parameters.) It sounds like it might be https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html  Check to see whether that URL is referenced in the code you are using.